# Is it possible to devise a O(n log n) sorting algorithm using these three procedures Max(A, i, j), Min(A, i, j) and Swap(A, i, j) only?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, max, min

Max(A, i, j) is a procedure that finds the maximum among the elements indexed from i to j of array A.
Min(A, i, j) is a procedure that finds the minimum among the elements indexed from i to j of array A.
Swap(A, i, j) is a procedure that swaps A[i] and A[j] on array A.

The time complexity of Min(A, i, j) and Max(A, i, j) is O(K) where K = j - i.
The time complexity of Swap(A, i, j) is O(1).

Note: This is not a homework problem as I'm a working professional but I have an upcoming entrance exam for Masters and this is one of the previous year's problems.
I can do this in O(n^2) time easily but I'm unable to divide this problem in half size every iteration and use Min, Max, and Swap to build the sorted output to get O(n log n) time complexity. In whichever way, I think it is coming to O(n^2).

I feel the question is incorrect with regard to the time complexity it wants.

Comment: If it's a homework, you probably need to mention that in the question, and say what kind of help your need. Helping people with their homework is fine, doing people's homework is quite another thing.

Comment: Hint: show that you can compare two elements A[i] and A[j] in O(1) by combining these operations.

Comment: @Henry, int minIndex = Min(A, i, j); int maxIndex = Max(A, i, j); if( minIndex > maxIndex ) Swap(A, minIndex, maxIndex);

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., This is not a homework problem as I'm a working professional but I have an upcoming entrance exam for Masters and this is one of the previous year's problems.

Comment: Here, this might help you. Just replace k by 0 and j-i i.e. This algorithm uses quick select, a variation of quick sort.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/

Comment: @learner-coder: Quickselect requires worst-case O(n²) time.

Comment: @ruakh Please check out that link and I wrongly mentioned quick select, its like quick select, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Any comparison-based in-place sort can be implemented at its normal complexity using these primitives.  To compare any 2 items, just swap them into positions 0 and 1, call Min(A,0,1), and swap them back.

Heapsort is the obvious choice for a comparison-based in-place sort with guaranteed O(n log n) time.

In heapsort, comparisons are used to find the maximum among mostly-adjacent items, so you can of course optimize your use of Min/Max to require fewer calls than the way mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

> Max(A, i, j) : can be done on O(N log N).

way:

1. clone all elements between (j-i) into new array/list
2. sort descending order using Merge/Quick sort.
3. return top most element from array/list

> Min(A, i, j): can be done on O(N log N)

way:

1. clone all elements between (j-i) into new array/list.
2. sort ascending order using Merge/Quick sort.
3. return top most element from array/list.

> Swap(A, i, j): can be done on O(1)

Over all complexity depicts:

O(N log N) + O(N log N) + O(1) = > O(N log N).

Comment: You misunderstood the question. It is not asking to implement those functions. They are already implemented (black box). The task is to design an efficient algorithm that uses only those functions. So there is no comparison operator you can use.

Comment: Also, `Min` and `Max` can be implemented more efficiently. The bounds given in the question are better than yours and trivially achievable.